# To maintain given value in select button using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My question is that I want to keep pre-selected {{k.toTime}} initially on select input. I am not able to view {{k.toTime}} or {{k.fromTime }} value as iniatially set in select input.
myFormat is my custom filter to convert minutes into hours.
My HTML Code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="k in workingHours" >
    <p>{{k.fromTime |  myFormat:'hr'}}:{{k.fromTime |  myFormat:'min'}}</p>
 </div>

<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="k.toTime"
     ng-options="time as (time | myFormat:'hr') +':'+ ( time | myFormat:'min') for time in minute " >
</select>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to initialize select field with give {{k.fromTime}} value

Comment: @SanketDhoble, you should post your controller (with the customFilter), your array data and then explain what you want clearly, then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question you want to *preselect* a value in your `<select>`, so here we go:

Put in your **controller:**

```
$scope.k.toTime = minutes[0];
```